# Why doesn't the Riemann Zeta Function have zeroes at positive even integers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

According to the [Wikipedia entry on "Riemann Functional Equation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), the Zeta Function is equal to itself multiplied by a bunch of stuff, including the term $$\sin(πs/2)$$ This sine term means that for negative even integers, the Zeta Function is 0. But why doesn't this apply to positive even integers? Is it because the negative even integer values of s create a divergent series, but the positive even integer values are convergent?

Comment: Hint: compare the limits of $\sin(\pi s/2) \Gamma(1-s)$ for positive and negative even integers.

Comment: As the page you linked to says, the pole of the $\Gamma$ term in the formula cancels it out.

Comment: More fundamentally, the functional equation is an analytic continuation of the Dirichlet series $$\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}\,,\quad\Re(s)>1$$ to $\Re(s)<0,$, and obviously the Dirichlet series does not evaluate to $0$ at positive even integers as in this case all terms of the series are positive rational numbers.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \zeta(s)=2^s\pi^{s-1}\sin\Big(\frac{\pi s}{2}\Big)\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s) $$

At positive odd integers, $\Gamma(1-s)$ has a pole, but none of the terms to the left of it in the equation have a zero or a pole, which forces $\zeta(1-s)$ to have a zero to "cancel out" the pole. Notice demonstrating $\zeta$ vanishes at negative even integers *uses* the fact $\zeta$ is nonzero for $s>1$. If we plug in positive even integers, $\Gamma(1-s)$ still has a pole but it is cancelled out by the sine term having a zero of the same order, which forces $\zeta(1-s)$ to actually be nonzero.